# Collapsed large title navigation bar becomes expanded after back navigation to root view controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I have UIViewController with vertical UIScrollView that has UIView as a container for all it's subviews. Here are my scrollView & contentView constraints:

```swift
        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

[image: ViewController]

When I scroll down my navigation bar gets smaller as it should be:

[image: Scrolled down ViewController]

Then I click on tableviewcell, navigate to detailVC and back. That's where the problem comes in. Somehow my navigation bar gets big until I scroll it in any direction, and then it jumps to it's normal state. Why is that happening and what could be the reason?

[image: Problem]

[Here](https://gist.github.com/IrelDev/ba034be3dfbe249b021c85b62b415939) is the gist with my ViewController code

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured my constraints and fixed that issue.

New constraints:

```swift
        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
       // contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = would be true if horizontal
        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```